# Find rules fired/matched for each fact

Tags: drools

Is there a way to find out which rules were matched (fired) whenever I insert a fact (POJO) (or whenever I fire all the rules).
I need to figure out for which facts none of the rules got fired and for each fact which of the rules got fired for some visualisation activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement method `void beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent event)` of the interface `org.kie.api.event.rule.AgendaEventListener`. The event will tell you a match: `Match getMatch()`, and the match informs you about facts: `List<? extends FactHandle> getFactHandles()` and the rule: `Rule getRule()`.

If you want to use another listener for keeping track of inserted facts, there is `org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener`, but you could do this just as well in the application code where you insert facts.

I guess you can imagine the rest: storing this information in a Map and evaluating it is a simple exercise.

Comment: I need to implement beforeMatchFired() or afterMatchFired(). Also how do I find the facts for which no rule is matched?

Comment: beforeMatchFired is sufficient for your purpose unless you need to inspect objects for changes. --- I told you that you need to keep track of all inserted facts. A `Map<Object,List<Rule>>` will tell you all rules where some fact has been used. And if the List is empty, it hasn't been used at all.

Comment: RuleRunTime event listener will also have to be implemented because there could even be rules inserting objects/facts which cannot be tracked via application alone.